# CTE: Union de duas tabelas em que uma delas apenas tem um campo em comum

Tags: sql, sql-server, cte

Necessito de fazer o seguinte com recurso a uma CTE.Imaginando duas tabelas com as colunas:

**Artigos:** Referência, Quantidade, Preço
**Referências Associadas:** Referência, RefAssociada

Pretendo que caso exista uma referência associada para uma referência da tabela Artigos, que devolva a informação da referência associada existente na tabela Artigos.

Exemplo:
**Artigos:**
RefA, 10, 7€
RefB, 5, 4€
RefC, 2, 10€

**Referências Associadas:**
RefA, RefC

**Resultado terá de ser:**
RefA, 10, 7€
RefC, 2, 10€
RefB, 5, 4€
RefC, 2, 10€

Answer (score 0):

Um select com join, acredito que seja suficiente:

```
    select Artigos.Referência,
   Artigos.Quantidade,
   Artigos.Preço,
   [Referências Associadas].RefAssociada from Artigos left join [Referências Associadas] on Artigos.Referência = [Referências Associadas].Referência
```

Comment: Não é uma solução, pois um artigo pode ter várias referências associadas. E quando existe  referências associadas deve ser acrescentada uma linha de seguida com a informação dessa referência.

Comment: Post as colunas das tabelas .